# jQuery click event on button firing multiple times?

Tags: jquery, onclick

It's been a long time since I used jQuery, so I'm a bit rusty. Having an issue with a click event on a simple button.
(I've tried going through every suggested question that seems like a similar issue. The solutions there don't seem to fix this.)
This is a form to change the year for output in a table (data retrieved via ajax, so no page refresh). The user will need to be able to change the year and submit the form multiple times.

```
<form id="toolbar-year-form">
    <input type="text" name="target-year">
    <button>Go</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#toolbar-year-form > button').off().on('click', function() {
        $('#toolbar-year-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert("submitted");
        });
    });

});
```

If I fill in the input and click the button, it works as expected. If I click it again without a page refresh, the event will then fire twice. If I click again, it fires three times. And so on...

The click event is being bound again each time I click, which explains the multiplication of firing, but I don't know why it's being bound again. :-)

What am I missing?

Comment: No need to `$('#toolbar-year-form > button').off().on('click', function() {` you can use `submit` event only .. submit event will catch the button click itself

Comment: Turns out using `$('#toolbar-year-form > button').one('click'...` did the trick.

Comment: Its not a trick while no need to use the submit inside the click .. It's enough to use the submit event without the click one

Comment: Won't the `.submit` in the document.ready just submit the form as soon as the page loads?

Comment: jQuery's submit function registers an event handler for the submit event the way you've used it. It triggers a submit event if you don't give it arguments. https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a button is not given a `type` attribute, it defaults to a `submit` button. You're binding a(nother) handler for form submission when the button is clicked, which is then immediately triggered by the button click because it's a `submit` button that is a child of the form. You can get the behaviour I believe you want by removing the outer event binding since clicking the button already submits the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#toolbar-year-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("submitted");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what @Mohamed-Yousef was saying, too. I thought the `.submit` in the `.ready` would just submit the form on page load.

Comment: Apparently, `.submit` does not do what I thought it did! Thanks!

Comment: `.submit()` does emit the submit event when not given any arguments, which is pretty confusing. Consider using the more explicit `.on( "submit", handler )` instead.